# Android Nkzawa SocketIO disconnect and make new connection

Tags: android, socket.io

I am working with android, socketio (nkzawa). When I connect the first time is working perfectly. But then If I disconnect and try to make "another connection" the EVENT_CONNECT is never called.

Here I put some snippets

When I connect

Inside BeforeActivity

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();   
    socketManager = (socketManager) socketManager.Instance(this, UrlHelper.URL.replaceAll("\\{userId\\}", userId.toString());
}
```

Then I have class SocketManager that extends from GenericSocket where I have a variable (SocketManager) instance for a singleton

```
public static SocketManager Instance(SocketListener listener, String url) {

  if (instance == null) {
    instance = new socketManager(url);
    instance.init();
  }

  socketManager.listener = (listener)listener;

  return instance;
}
```

and the initialization of the socket is done in the class GenericSocket where I have a variable of type (com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket ) tcalled socket

```
protected void init() {
    try {
        socket = IO.socket(url);
        socket
        .on(com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                onConnect();
                JSONObject connectionMessage = getConnectionMessage();
                socket.emit(MESSAGE_JOIN, connectionMessage);
            }

        }).on(MESSAGE, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Object data = args[0];
                if (data instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) data;
                    try {
                        onMessage(json.get("content").toString());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    onMessage(data.toString());
                }

            }
        }).on(Constant.CONNECTION, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Object data = args[0];
                if (data instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) data;
                    try {
                        onMessage(json.get("content").toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    onMessage(data.toString());
                }

            }
        }).on(com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                onDisconnect();
            }
        });
        socket.connect();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Socket connection error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    //end socket connection
}
```

and when I disconnect

The disconnect is like this inside SocketManager class I have this method

```
public void disconnect() {
  this.socket.disconnect();
  this.socket=null;
  SocketManager.instance = null;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Code of your implementation of disconnect socket would be very helpful

Comment: @jimmy0251 I updated, I hope this is a little more clear. Thank you

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try putting this.socket.off() before socket.disconnect(). I had an issue where server was keeping my connection alive even after disconnect(), socket.off() worked for me.

Comment: And you are calling disconnect method on onPause() callback of Activity right?

Comment: @jimmy0251thank you for your answer now I will try with socket.off(). But I am not calling on the onpause, I am calling manually, because an event on my application triggers that.

Comment: @jimmy0251the socket.off() didn't work at first, but then I updated the nkzawa library and is working, thank you for your comments now I have solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71911/discussion-between-agusgambina-and-jimmy0251).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Try putting this.socket.off() before socket.disconnect(). I had an issue where server was keeping my connection alive even after disconnect(), socket.off() worked for me.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as I told you I need to do that and also update the nkzawa socket version from 0.2.1 to 0.4.0. thank you

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but it might help someone -> I solved it by a combination of this answer and updating the [lib to 1.0.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java). Cheers!